# Enable Passwordless Sudo with Arguments

Tags: rhel6, sudo, capistrano

I am trying to enable passwordless sudo for updating yum on a RHEL box. I have the following line in sudo visudo.

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/yum update
```

After doing this under myuser I am still unable to update yum without giving my sudo password.

- `/usr/bin/env sudo yum -y update`
- `sudo yum -y update`

The reason why I need this done is because in Capistrano 3 it says this is the best way. It does not seem to allow a prompt of sudo anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup passwordless \`sudo\` on Linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux)

Comment: It's not a duplicate as it's a different problem. The problem there does not reference the need to have the extra parameter in the sudoers file. I thought it would automatically pick that up and know about it.

Comment: @wallerjake, I've changed the **redhat** tag with **rhel6**, as [**redhat**](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/redhat) is way too generic. If you're using a different version, please update the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the command string listed in the sudoers is requiring to be the exact match.

In your example, you put the command string `/usr/bin/yum update` in the sudoers configuration line, but the command you finally executes is `yum -y update`. (the difference is the extra parameter `-y`).

Then, the mismatch in command string caused the sudoers failed to hit the designed definition.

So, the following ways are my suggestion to rectify the problem:

1. use the command string `/usr/bin/yum -y update` when you setting the sudoer configuration, or
2. use the command string `/usr/bin/yum` (no parameter in there).

Comment: This was a great answer. The part I was missing was having the -y in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> Cmnd_Alias YUM = /usr/bin/yum
>
> user ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: YUM

Comment: You might also have to comment out the requiretty setting: "Defaults    requiretty" if you are using SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the following in your `sudoers` file :

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If yes, try to comment it :

```
#%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```