# create user without password in ubuntu with su access?

Tags: linux, centos, login, user-accounts

I am trying to create a user with `su` access on `centos`.
I followed the instructions from this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192945/user-without-a-password-how-can-one-login-into-that-account-from-a-non-root-ac). but NOTHING worked.

I want to login using `su test_user`

steps:

`sudo adduser test_user`
(No prompt to set up password)

I tried `su test_user` (prompted for password)
(pressed entered key - did not work)

then I deleted password

```
sudo passwd -d test_user
Removing password for user test_user.
passwd: Success
```

Then I tried

```
su test_user 
Password: (just enter key pressed)
su: Permission denied
```

NOTE: I also changed my `sudoers` file to reflect the following at the end of file `/etc/sudoers` as indicated in this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux).

`test_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

still nothing worked. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Either you want 'normal_user' to be able to 'su' to into 'test_user', or you want 'test_user' to able to to become root or to be able to run a command that requires root privilege. Those are all different cases.

Comment: @MarkStosberg: first case. thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, to be clear, `su` and `sudo` are completely different things. Adding test_user to your sudoers file is completely irrelevant for this use case.

`su` allows you to switch from one user to another, while `sudo` allow you to run a command as a different user. There's a subtle difference.

Having a passwordless account is *horrible* idea. Don't do it.

If you want to be able to switch from one account to another without affecting the other account's password, then just do:

```
$ sudo su - username
```

It goes without saying that your user account will need to be added to sudoers with the appropriate access to run the above command as root.

Comment: Thanks. will  `sudo su username` gets all privileges of sudo ( i mean run all commands). I want to switch from one to user but still have privileges to run commands

Comment: You *do* have privileges to run commands.

Comment: and the privileges is there because I added it to the sudoers files?

Comment: The sudoers file has absolutely nothing to do with **anything** except running commands via `sudo`.

Comment: I still don't get it. you say `su` allows you to switch from one user to another. so why `su test_user` prompts for password but `sudo su test_user` does not?

Comment: Read my answer. It is because when you're running the command via `sudo`, it is running with root's privileges. Root does not need to specify passwords when switching from one user to another.

Comment: I get that. how can i get `su test_user` to work then instead of `sudo su test_user`?

Comment: You don't. You use sudo.

Comment: I don't or I cannot. and from my understanding from comments, the line I added to my sudoers file makes no difference?

Comment: Again. As I said in my answer - `su`, and `/etc/sudoers` have **absolutely nothing to do with each other**. `su` knows nothing about what is in your sudoers file. Nothing.

Comment: ok ok. so "I don't or I cannot" - please make that clear. I remember issuing `su someuseName` before. so wondering how that worked then

Comment: If you want your normal user to be able to "su" into testuser without a password, EEAA's answer above is the correct answer: Use "sudo su testuser" to access the account.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest otherwise http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192956/36253 but testing it out, `su` still prompts for a password after deleting it. I am aware it is a security risk, just curious how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Create an user with empty password**

```
sudo useradd test-user-0
echo test-user-0:U6aMy0wojraho | sudo chpasswd -e
su test-user-0
```

The password prompt still shows unfortunately.

But if you just hit enter without typing anything, and it logins as the user `test-user-0`.

The `-e` flags tells `chpasswd` that the password is already encrypted, and `U6aMy0wojraho` is the hash of the empty string.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**BusyBox autologin**

On the terminal at least, you don't need to create an user without a password to allow someone to not type their passwords everytime, hacking `inittab` a bit is enough: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build