# run command as another user in Linux without password

Tags: linux

my user is not root in the machine. when I run :

```
sudo su - user2
```

I switch to the user2 without password prompt.

when I run

```
sudo su - user2 < file_contains_commandLines
```

I can run the commands in the file "file_contains_commandLines" as the user user2 - also without typing my password

However when I run

```
sudo -u user2 ls
```

or

```
sudo su - user2 -c "ls"
```

I should enter my password and i got

```
Sorry, user myUser is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as user2 on machinexyz.
```

How can I pass the list of command to be executed as the user2 without having to enter my password ... since I can run sudo su - user2!

I want to avoid to pass my commands via a document as follow:

```
sudo su - user2 < file_contains_commandLines
```

Comment: Does sudo su - user2 -c "ll" work? I know ls isn't valid on any of my servers when using sudo. I'm sure there is a reason but I can't be bothered figuring it out as it isn't a big issue for me. However, if ll works for you it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: not working as well, same result : it demands my password (it shouldnt) and it says : Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - user2 -c ll'

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/160587/200560

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup passwordless \`sudo\` on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux)

Comment: I modified one of my /etc/sudoers on a server and was able to run sudo commands without a password. Jacob's link also confirms it https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux/160587#160587

Comment: You have only configured passwordless sudo to the root user. With your first command you execute the command "su - user2" as user root. The root user can su to any user without password.